# Docker Desktop for Windows: No hypervisor is present on this system

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am new to **Docker Desktop for Windows**. I am getting an error when I tried the hello world example by following [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/). **Update**

Below is the steps I followed:

1 [Installed Docker for Windows, stable version](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/)

2 [Both Hyper-V and Virtualization have been enabled on my Windows 10](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#hyper-v)

However, error below when switch to Linux container:

> An error occurred.
>   Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled

Please note the problem in this post occurs when using Windows containers. Step 3 is using Windows containers, not Linux.

3 [Error below when trying out hello world](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#explore-the-application-and-run-examples)

```
PS C:\Users\'#.lp> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
407ada6e90de: Pull complete
9c9e16cbf19f: Pull complete
2cb715c55064: Pull complete
990867d1296d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:445b2fe9afea8b4aa0b2f27fe49dd6ad130dfe7a8fd0832be5de99625dad47cd
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container e646da0e13b5c2ba92db3ade35f6a334f9c2903efde26a78765f55f0498a86f1 encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: No hypervisor is present on this system. (0xc0351000) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"e646da0e13b5c2ba92db3ade35f6a334f9c2903efde26a78765f55f0498a86f1","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\e646da0e13b5c2ba92db3ade35f6a334f9c2903efde26a78765f55f0498a86f1","Layers":[{"ID":"84cbd4e4-1a6a-5e55-86fa-927ba5be73e0","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\417caa6a366bad6fe0d68d2b459510e4c50fda5686b37fb91c9363ca103e9475"},{"ID":"e747017d-859e-5513-b9ad-346002efc167","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\43e4d5eeaebc150ea9da0bf919302a2d7646461e3da60b5cbd3db15d3d928698"},{"ID":"e0bd7f8a-622c-589f-9752-eb7b80b88973","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\e8ee5f9ec8d67bfebe230b67989dd788506e33627a4400bb63ba098b2a3fd733"},{"ID":"6f13d213-2d8c-5c37-b1f5-770f73ad2d9a","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\a731844c4d933200e984524b7273ac3a555792bafec6eab30722fdfd7992ee96"}],"HostName":"e646da0e13b5","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["0b88e638-56ea-4157-88a7-67fc3bc35958"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\e8ee5f9ec8d67bfebe230b67989dd788506e33627a4400bb63ba098b2a3fd733\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}.
```

System information below:

```
   PS C:\Users\'#.lp> docker --version
Docker version 17.09.1-ce, build 19e2cf6
PS C:\Users\'#.lp> docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 17.09.1-ce
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 16299 (16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534)
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.999GiB
Name: username
ID: 5EK5:6LMU:NPZG:3K2F:W3X7:2G7T:GFYU:GENE:LDBA:UASU:ZF26:T3AU
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 24
 System Time: 2017-12-24T20:16:32.0728521Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false


PS C:\Users\'#.lp> docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build 6d101fb0
PS C:\Users\'#.lp> docker-machine --version
docker-machine.exe version 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9
```

Windows 10 Pro version 1709

Any idea?

**Update**:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker --version
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
a7094c166be7
afbc956d0630
6cc2e3a20dcc
e646da0e13b5
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
Untagged: hello-world:latest
Untagged: hello-world@sha256:445b2fe9afea8b4aa0b2f27fe49dd6ad130dfe7a8fd0832be5de99625dad47cd
Deleted: sha256:29528317da62a27024338f18abf29c992d6cdb4087f7d195cb6725bbe6bd15cc
Deleted: sha256:729a95d3f7234b02c27bdaf4fd81fd3fb9453445a85b713398c6bd05ad290ff5
Deleted: sha256:fcea8c486bda6858dee33a0ce494fba4839e542554b0588f6d00833a4155a537
Deleted: sha256:53cda6d9c060289530670af7ac429015f88d1ac58417f94f22c3dd2f03210436
Deleted: sha256:67903cf26ef4095868687002e3dc6f78ad275677704bf0d11524f16209cec48e
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
407ada6e90de: Pull complete
711a33cda32c: Pull complete
f2954926b3d8: Pull complete
8b6a3aeeca73: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:66ef312bbac49c39a89aa9bcc3cb4f3c9e7de3788c944158df3ee0176d32b751
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container 99a306c2336a7bd503bfe8a744ace77cedc19bbc0d15e52b8d899bcea3db6b96 encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: No hypervisor is present on this system. (0xc0351000) extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"99a306c2336a7bd503bfe8a744ace77cedc19bbc0d15e52b8d899bcea3db6b96","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\99a306c2336a7bd503bfe8a744ace77cedc19bbc0d15e52b8d899bcea3db6b96","Layers":[{"ID":"a5eef81d-74bf-53d1-8517-78b635324fdb","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\afb89f854af8452a0a12dfb14dc47995e001057c7af209be45ed5ee4813d2ffd"},{"ID":"744a6817-2b8a-5b6a-a717-8932a5863c9f","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\21a39c2b74ff220eac42f6f96d6097a7ef0feb192c1a77c0e88068cd10207d33"},{"ID":"ee281c98-febf-545b-bd51-8aec0a88f617","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\62439684561a3d30068cae2c804512984637d4c8b489f6f7cbcb5c8fed588af5"},{"ID":"f023cffb-ac18-57fe-9894-a2f1798fd0b0","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\1354f5a762901ec48bcf6a3ca8aab615bc305e91315e6e77fdf2c8fee5d587a2"}],"HostName":"99a306c2336a","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["2ce5269d-8776-4e84-8b37-4d99fa0a9f7b"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\62439684561a3d30068cae2c804512984637d4c8b489f6f7cbcb5c8fed588af5\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> systeminfo

Host Name:                 XXXX
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.16299 N/A Build 16299
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          '#.lp
Registered Organization:
Product ID:                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Original Install Date:     10/12/2017, 23:15:17
System Boot Time:          06/01/2018, 13:53:55
System Manufacturer:       System manufacturer
System Model:              System Product Name
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 11 GenuineIntel ~2401 Mhz
BIOS Version:              American Megatrends Inc. 0902   , 27/07/2011
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-gb;English (United Kingdom)
Input Locale:              en-gb;English (United Kingdom)
Time Zone:                 (UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
Total Physical Memory:     8,191 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2,209 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  16,383 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 4,745 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    11,638 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
Logon Server:              \\XXXXX
Hotfix(s):                 7 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB4048951
                           [02]: KB4053577
                           [03]: KB4054022
                           [04]: KB4055237
                           [05]: KB4056887
                           [06]: KB4058043
                           [07]: KB4054517
Network Card(s):           5 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: TunnelBear Adapter V9
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [02]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
                                 Connection Name: Local Area Connection
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [03]: Compact Wireless-G USB Network Adapter
                                 Connection Name: Wi-Fi
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     XXXXX
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: XXX
                                 [02]: XXX
                           [04]: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
                                 Connection Name: vEthernet (Default Switch)
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     255.255.255.255
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: X
                                 [02]: X
                           [05]: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
                                 Connection Name: vEthernet (nat)
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     255.255.255.255
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: X
                                 [02]: X
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: No
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

**Update 2**

Still getting the same error, any idea?

```
PS C:\Users\'#.lp> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
e46172273a4e: Pull complete
61703422ec93: Pull complete
a17b8d9caad6: Pull complete
2dccc7619f71: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:41a65640635299bab090f783209c1e3a3f11934cf7756b09cb2f1e02147c6ed8
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: CreateComputeSystem 755110bc7813700701f2325c921fad7a4220c8ff91d620ac51e258cb8b1ab700: No hypervisor is present on this system.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"755110bc7813700701f2325c921fad7a4220c8ff91d620ac51e258cb8b1ab700","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\755110bc7813700701f2325c921fad7a4220c8ff91d620ac51e258cb8b1ab700","Layers":[{"ID":"535189fb-71a2-598a-bd98-f711c29cf301","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\5e4cc131c334b8171b269003b9659ba578f9528372dd28054624d0bbde003b4f"},{"ID":"93d17dd0-2837-5522-a207-2b9e009a9d2b","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\87d235bd8d5ca1534f7396bf90d96ee9012875f8ae0e56556af19ebce73cdf80"},{"ID":"6899fe53-2cd7-5ec6-8edc-bf8859eea3e7","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\f75a64ae1fe066c392738bc643e1f49f1f0ee0bce4214c8655714b7386cdc3fc"},{"ID":"efbc003d-b691-5d30-ad65-d7dff28ca9e8","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\74033dce6b43107101f831d96c6bebe0ceb1df34f8e5c82421ee3f296b20a70c"}],"HostName":"755110bc7813","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["93c1c71e-11b5-49d3-82fd-d467d9b625b6"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\f75a64ae1fe066c392738bc643e1f49f1f0ee0bce4214c8655714b7386cdc3fc\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}).
PS C:\Users\'#.lp> docker --version
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
PS C:\Users\'#.lp>
```

Comment: Try to use Docker Toolbox. It will install Kitematic also. It's a better solution for Windows OS.

Comment: Is  Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection enabled just like the error suggests? What is the make and model of computer?

Comment: On step 2, OS shows that both Hyper-V and Virtualization are enabled. I cannot see data execution protection settings in my BIOS.

Answer (score 25):

Here is what worked for me: Open command prompt as admin and run

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

and then **reboot**

What had happened:
I had to start an android emulator and Android Studio said that "Emulator is incompatible With Hyper-V" so it ran this command to disable hyper-v `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

Comment: first I ran this line, nothing changed. I have aleady installed and unistalled the oracle vbox. after I installed it again and ran the line it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

These steps fixed it:

```
1. bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto 
2. reboot computer 
3. docker run hello-world
```

Comment: Thats a Neat list of steps to follow :-) That should solve my issues with DOCKER :-)

Answer (score 5):

if both docker and Hyper-V are installed try to recreate the image in docker. It works for me.

You can check the status of Hyper-V in system by typing the following command in powershell:

```
systeminfo
```

You should also switch to container for windows in docker if not already.

Comment: container for windows is already turned on. How to recreate the Image? Will  that help at all? I got error when I run "docker run hello-world"

Comment: please refer to my updated post. I deleted images, and upgrades to a newer version of Docker, and re-tried hello-world, but still the same error.

Comment: @Pingpong "systeminfo" command from the powershell tell you if Hyper-V is enabled.
To delete images and try to refer to the docs: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/

Comment: The information on the result after following your instruction had already updated at the bottom of the post. The problem still exists.

Comment: yes, pls refer to the bottom of my updated post. liike below: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
..
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
..

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem.
Had to enable the virtualization in the BIOS to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're attempting to run Docker for Windows inside a Parallels virtual machine, you must enable 'Nested Virtualization'.

https://kb.parallels.com/en/116239

This is only available in the Pro and Business Editions.  I had to upgrade my version to support this as I was running Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Docker in a VM, may be you need look into "Nested Virtualization", the Virtualization need to be exposed from Physical Server to VM.

For example, expose Virtualization in Hyper-V platform throuth powershell scripts:

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

see the link:
[Run Hyper-V in a Virtual Machine with Nested Virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization)

Comment: And Docker had required SLAT, it seems your CPU doesn't support, I can see " Second Level Address Translation: No" in your post

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue and it got resolved after upgrading my windows to latest version...

Comment: what version have you installed? Wins 10 pro ?

Comment: what version of Docker have you installed? 3 questions in total

Comment: I have latest windows, but still have the same issue. Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.192]

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.192]
Docker version: 17.12.0-ce-win47

Comment: Also refer https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1221 if above does not solve the issue.

Comment: we are using the same windows version and Docker version, but mine is not working. STRANGE!!

Answer (score 1):

I did everything as suggested on this post and others to no avail. What did work for me was the following:

1. Turn Windows Features OFF : Hyper-V and Containers
2. Force an windows update to Windows 10 Pro ver: 1803

The update completed. Then when I started docker it asked me if I wanted to enable Hyper-V and Containers. I answered yes. The machine rebooted twice.

After this everything worked perfectly. Unfortunately I cannot say for sure if point 1 or point 2 or both together fixed the issue. I would suggest try point 1 above first followed by a reboot then starting docker. I suspect this rather than forcing a update to Windows 1803 will fix the problem.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info. I will try it and update the ticket with result.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling BIOS visualization works for me.

### For people who use Asus motherboard AND **AMD** CPU to enable the visualization.

1. Go to BIOS (restart, press del, all that cr*p)
2. Advanced
3. CPU Configuration
4. Toggle SVM mode to "Enabled" (I missed that because it does not mention the full word "Visualization" like intel does)

### You will likely encounter the error "Docker Desktop requires a newer WSL kernel version."

Powershell with admin privilege

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart
```

Download and install [WSL2 linux kernel update package](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi)

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

Restart

Done

PC spec:
Windows 10 Home
21H2
19044

Answer (score 0):

For virtualbox users you need to enable nested virtualization

```
VM -> Configuration -> System -> Processor -> Enable nested VT-x/AMD-v
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command on Windows Power Shell

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`

if it requires a restart, then just follow the steps.

more info or options, please check [docs from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1:

Uninstall Docker.

### Step 2:

Open "Turn windows features on or off" from Control Panel.
**Uncheck** both features - "Containers" and "Hyper-V", if they are checked.

[image]

### Step 3:

Reboot PC

### Step 4:

**Check** both features - "Container" and "Hyper-V".

[image]

### Step 5:

Reboot PC.

### Step 6:

Install docker and execute `docker run hello-world`

Comment: Tried that before posting the question. Not working.

Comment: There is no rationale in this answer as to why this would fix OP's problem and it indeed did not help.

Answer (score 0):

BIOS LEVEL Virtualization is a must

Hyper-V and Containers Windows features must be enabled.
The following hardware prerequisites are required to successfully run Client Hyper-V on Windows 10:

64-bit processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
4GB system RAM
BIOS-level hardware virtualization support must be enabled in the BIOS settings.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/